# PowerShell NewMsolUser cmdlet ParameterBindingException Error When I Save PowerShell script into .ps1 file

Tags: powershell, office365, ms-office

I get errors when i save the following PowerShell script into `.ps1 file`. Let me know what is not right or needs to be added to the `.ps1 file` to suppress the error because generally the script is correct.

When i paste the following script content in powershell terminal, it runs correctly without errors and users are created successfully.

```
Import-CSV "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\users.csv" | ForEach-Object { New-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName -FirstName $_.FirstName -LastName $_.LastName  -DisplayName "$($_.FirstName) $($_.LastName)" –Password $_.Password –UsageLocation "US" -ForceChangePassword ([System.Convert]::ToBoolean($_.ForceChangePassword))}
```

But when i save the same script into `script.ps1 file` and then run it, i get the following errors in the snapshot attached.

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: It's about the dash in front of parameter `Password`. Just retype that to become a `-` hyphen.

Comment: But its already an hyphen! Or which one do you prefer?

Comment: No, it isn't. Look closely, you will see it is slightly longer than a normal hyphen. Right now, it is an `en-dash` (or `em-dash`) probably from copying off the internet. The same is in front of parameter `UsageLocation`, so you need to retype that as well.

Comment: Thank you Theo. Have seen it. Have noticed PowerShell ignores the dash, but the ps ps1 file does not. I appreciate your kind response.